# Server disconnects in Java

Tags: java, client, stream, disconnect

Related posts didn't answer my question.

I have a server which does something like:

```
EVERY TWO SECONDS DO: 
if the inputstream is not null {
     if inputStream.available() is 0 
     {
          return 
     }
     print "handling input stream"
     handleTheInputStream(); 
}
```

Even after my client disconnects, the server doesn't recognize it through an IOException.  The other post said that I would see an End-of-Stream character.  However, that is not the case, since after my client disconnects I never see "handling input stream" which indicates that no data is available.

Perhaps something is wrong with the way I currently understand how this works.

Please help.

Comment: I think your pseudo-code is broken. If the input stream is null then inputStream.available() will throw an NPE...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Supposed to be "inputstream is not null AND..."

Comment: In which case I suspect you've now got the branches wrong... why would you want to handle the input stream if it's either null or doesn't have any data?

Comment: Correct, still broken.  Will fix.

Comment: Hi jbu, I hope you got your code working.  I'd like to suggest that, since this a community website, you consider leaving questions open once answered.  Even if the issue is obvious in retrospect, others who have similar/identical problems will then be able to learn from the problem-solving process.

Comment: (I'm assuming here that there wasn't another reason for other question being deleted.  If so, please ignore these comments.)

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `available()` - that says whether or not there's *currently* data available, not whether there *will* be data available in the future. In other words, it's the wrong tool to use to detect disconnection.

Basically you should call `read()` (and process the data) until it returns -1, at which point it means the client has disconnected.

Comment: Read returns -1 when the client has disconnected.

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to change existing code in the server since I didn't write it.  I CAN change it, but I'd like to know there isn't any other way to do it before I request to change.  Changing would require lots of regression testing.

Comment: Addition: I am simply changing the handleInputStream() method.

Comment: @jbu: Well, we don't know anything else about the code - but using available() is certainly not the way to detect disconnects. I can't remember the last time I saw a *valid* use for available() to be honest.

Comment: Yes, the API for available() is not clear to me.  I am not sure what "Returns the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next caller of a method for this input stream." means exactly and what the implications are.

Comment: Basically it says "is there any data available *right now*". Absence of data right now doesn't mean the stream has finished. On the other hand, it *might*. You really need to read from the stream, and if it returns -1 then the stream has *definitely* finished.

Answer (score 1):

If this is done using sockets, you may want to check the [Socket](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class's various instance methods, such as [isClosed()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isClosed()) or [isInputShutdown()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isInputShutdown()).

Of course, this assumes that the method operating on this stream has access to the Socket object and not just the InputStream.